# Opening a page from DOM in current tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

On button click a PHP function is called where I use file_get_html() from Simple HTML DOM Parser to edit a form in the html file. I want to replace the current page with the edited DOM . I tried using javascript, document.write and window.open in various ways but it eitherappends the new page to current page or nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'your html';
```

if you want to change the content of the page, or

```
location.href = 'some.url';
```

if you want to open a new url in the same page